Помогите задать второго администратора для бота Telegram на Python (aiogram)
Всем привет! Помогите добавить второго администратора, у которого будет доступ к соответствующим функциям. Перепробовал большинство методов (создавал вторую переменную, передавал в переменную ADMIN_ID два значения через or, and и в квадратных скобка), но ничего не помогает. Что можно сделать, чтобы было два администратора, у которых будут права доступа на использование соответствующих функций?
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, types
from aiogram.contrib.fsm_storage.memory import MemoryStorage
from aiogram.dispatcher import FSMContext
from aiogram.dispatcher.filters.state import State, StatesGroup
from aiogram.types import ReplyKeyboardMarkup, KeyboardButton, InlineKeyboardMarkup, InlineKeyboardButton
from aiogram.utils import executor
import psycopg2
import re
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import asyncio

# Bot Token
TOKEN = 'xxxxxxxx'
bot = Bot(token=TOKEN)
storage = MemoryStorage()
dp = Dispatcher(bot, storage=storage)

# Настройки подключения к Базе Данных
DB_NAME = "xxxxxx"
DB_USER = "xxxxxx"
DB_PASSWORD = "xxxxx"
DB_HOST = "xxxxxx"

# Channel ID
CHANNEL_ID = "xxxxx"


def get_db_connection():
    conn = psycopg2.connect(dbname=DB_NAME, user=DB_USER,
                            password=DB_PASSWORD, host=DB_HOST)
    return conn


# Admin ID
ADMIN_ID = xxxxxxxx


# Классы для хранения состояний
class Form(StatesGroup):
    waiting_for_answer = State()
    waiting_for_broadcast = State()
    waiting_for_post = State()
    waiting_for_scheduled_time = State()


# Функция для записи обращения в базу данных и возврата ID созданной записи
def save_support_request(user_id, username, message):
    conn = get_db_connection()
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO support_requests (user_id, username, message) VALUES (%s, %s, %s) RETURNING id",
                (user_id, username, message))
    request_id = cur.fetchone()[0]  # Получаем id созданной записи
    conn.commit()
    cur.close()
    conn.close()
    return request_id


# Проверка на эмодзи
def contains_emoji(s):
    return bool(re.search(r'[\U00010000-\U0010ffff]', s))


# Проверка, заблокирован ли пользователь
def is_user_blocked(user_id):
    conn = get_db_connection()
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute("SELECT 1 FROM blocked_users WHERE user_id = %s", (user_id,))
    result = cur.fetchone()
    cur.close()
    conn.close()
    return result is not None


# Блокировка пользователя
def block_user(username):
    conn = get_db_connection()
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute("SELECT user_id FROM support_requests WHERE username = %s", (username,))
    user_id = cur.fetchone()
    if user_id:
        cur.execute("INSERT INTO blocked_users (user_id, username) VALUES (%s, %s)", (user_id[0], username))
        conn.commit()
    cur.close()
    conn.close()


# Разблокировка пользователя
def unblock_user(username):
    conn = get_db_connection()
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute("DELETE FROM blocked_users WHERE username = %s", (username,))
    conn.commit()
    cur.close()
    conn.close()


# Обработчик для команды /start
@dp.message_handler(commands=['start'])
async def send_welcome(message: types.Message):
    if message.chat.id != ADMIN_ID:
        if is_user_blocked(message.chat.id):
            await message.reply("Вы заблокированы и не можете отправлять сообщения.")
        else:
            await message.reply("Добро пожаловать! Напишите свое обращение, и наша поддержка скоро свяжется с вами.")
    else:
        markup = ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
        markup.add(KeyboardButton("Запросы"))
        markup.add(KeyboardButton("Административная панель"))
        await bot.send_message(ADMIN_ID, "Выберите опцию:", reply_markup=markup)


# Обработчик для кнопки "Административная панель"
@dp.message_handler(lambda message: message.chat.id == ADMIN_ID and message.text == "Административная панель")
async def admin_panel(message: types.Message):
    markup = ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
    markup.add(KeyboardButton("Рассылка"))
    markup.add(KeyboardButton("Черный список"))
    markup.add(KeyboardButton("Постинг"))
    await bot.send_message(ADMIN_ID, "Выберите опцию: ", reply_markup=markup)

# Запуск бота
if name == 'main':
    executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)


Возможный дубликат

@Ersamuel , нужно не с помощью бота назначить пользователя администратором, а в боте в коде дать права администратора второму пользователю

Есть вариант: пусть ADMIN_ID будет кортежом.
А строчку:
if message.chat.id != ADMIN_ID:

замените на:
if message.chat.id not in ADMIN_ID

ну и все остальное корртектируйте под кортеж.
подскажу - строки:
await bot.send_message(ADMIN_ID, "Выберите опцию:", reply_markup=markup)

замените на:
await bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Выберите опцию:", reply_markup=markup)

все равно проверку на админа человек прошел.
